# Statically determing unused code path in Android apk

Tags: android, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I want to statically determine unused code path in Android apk i.e. I want to find out all paths in .dex file that my code will never reach. What are the possible ways to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the javac compiler doesn't generate dead code.  If something can be statically determined to be unreachable, the compile will fail.  For example:

```
void foo() {
    throw new RuntimeException();

    doStuff();
}
```

This results in an "unreachable statement" failure.  You can "hint" to the compiler that you want to do this anyway:

```
void foo() {
    if (true) throw new RuntimeException();

    doStuff();
}
```

However, the compiler still knows that the call to doStuff() is unreachable, and discards it.

If you did manage to get dead code into a DEX file, the bytecode verifier will optionally tell you about it -- look for `DEAD_CODE_SCAN` in the [verifier source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/jb-mr2-release/vm/analysis/CodeVerify.cpp).

All of that is for dead code inside a method.  For identifying whole methods that are never actually called, you can use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) (which is an optional but officially supported part of Android app builds).  This can false-positive and remove methods that are never called directly but may be called through reflection, so manual overrides are sometimes required.